Scaling edges with Geometry Nodes
Can anyone help me achieve this offset edge with Geometry Nodes? I have created an attribute I created in Python for the edges (called freestyle_edge) that allows me to access this edge. Now how do I offset the edge? It was suggested to scale the edge along the surface normal, but I haven't been able to do this correctly. Thank you!



Is it the only shape of edges that should work or do you want a general solution ? Should the edge stay connected to the mesh or do you want only the edge as output ? I can think of a solution but it would be convoluted, if it works at all. Also, providing your blend file would be easier for us than to second guess your setup https://blend-exchange.com/.

@Lutzi Thank you for the reply. I have uploaded my blend file in the original post. The idea would be to use the new outline curves in Geo Nodes for points to place instances along the surface. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Then it's not about moving an edge but about placing down instances on the surface near the edge ? Your question is still unclear to me.

@Lutzi they're talking about essentially doing the "Edge > Offset Edge Slide " but in GN

@Lutzi It could be both. With the offset edges, I will be later distributing instances along them, but if you see a way to achieve that without offsetting the edges, it might be helpful. Moving the edge along the surface seems like a necessary first step for placing instances (giving control over the count and position), so I've started there to simplify the task.

Well it would help if you explain your final goal, i.e. what do you want to do with this edge afterwards exactly ? A quick drawing would be great (grease pencil is your friend). I'm not so sure that sliding the edge is the way to go, but I can't know till further informations.

@Lutzi I don't know what else to say. I want to distribute instances along this edge. It's just like Jakemoyo said - the edge would slide along the surface. If you don't get it, don't worry about it. I did draw where I want the instances in the blend file you requested. Thanks for your time.

Approximative solution
Here is a not-so-complex way of doing it. For a small offset, it works. But for bigger offset, then the shape changes. So it isn't at all equivalent to the G+G shortcut in Edit Mode.
The idea is to get the vector on which the vertex should slide by cross-producting the normal of the mesh and the tangent of the curve. Once we have it, we can slide the vertices left or right along that vector.
Depending on the curvature of the surface, the vertices will slowly move away from the surface. This is noticeable on the sphere, but not an issue on the wave plane. To fix this, we simply move the vertices to the nearest surface. Here are the nodes :

To control the sliding, there is an input to the modifier.
And here is an animation, showing that it works mainly close to the original edge.

And finally the blend file :

Improvement
This solution doesn't take into account the corners, which should move by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$. The previous Sliding direction could be replaced by that :

The lighter block is trying to detect if the current point is a corner. You'll have to tweak the threshold if it doesn't work for some other shapes. Prone to bugs if the shape isn't smooth enough.



This is very helpful of you, thank you, Lutzi!!!!

@Dr.Pontchartrain You're welcome. I've updated it with a correction for the corners.

That works great!! Looks fantastic! Thank you

Here's my strategy:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

You don't need the "Greater Than" node if the threshold is zero, because that's the implicit coercion
Remove all points but corners, so that the scaling doesn't distort desired rectangular shape.
Calculate the offsets and apply them to two copies of the rectangle.
Join rectangles and resample them with high resolution (0.01), so that the base curve tightly fits the mesh.
Snap the curve onto the nearest surface of the mesh.
Resample again with desired density of instances (0.1).
Instance on points. Instead of using original, captured normals, that could have ugly interpolation, I just sample nearest surface's normal. Notice how I capture it on point domain to get smooth interpolation of the normal.


Imgur mirror
If you're dissatisfied with the horizontal edge shape, then maybe raycasting should be used, using origin ($<0, 0, 0>$) as ray start, and position flattened on z axis (multiply by $<1, 1, 0>$) as ray direction?
Isolate Corners

Imgur mirror

Compare tangent - if it changed too little compared to previous, or next point, delete the point as it's not a corner.

Even Offset

Imgur mirror

Move a point away from previous point.
But also move it away from next point.
Since both offsets are normalized, they are equal, so you get even inset/outset distance regardless of rectangle dimensions.



Brilliant, Markus! I really appreciate your work and the options you provided. Very kind and helpful. Thank you.
